# Gronwall's inequality for $\dot{x}(t) \le -c|x(t)|^p$, with $c>0$ and $0 < p \le 1$ fixed constant.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-inequality

Let $c > 0$ and $0 < p \le 1$ be fixed.

> **Question.** What does Gronwall's inequality say about solutions $t \mapsto x_p(t)$ of the differential inequation
> $$
> \dot{x}(t) \le -c|x(t)|^p,\;\forall t \in \mathbb R. \tag{1}
> $$

**Note (to check!).** The the properties (i.e inequalities) for $t \mapsto x_1(t)$ can be obtained from $t \mapsto x_p(t)$ (with $0 < p < 1$), by passing  the limit $p \to 1$ and using continuity.